# object of abstract type "NumericQuestion" is not allowed in c++

Tags: c++

Also, what does this code doing exactly?

```
const int MAX_QUESTIONS = 100;
Question* questions[MAX_QUESTIONS];
questions[numQuestions++] = createQuestion("How many degrees are there in a full circle?", 360);
```

and

```
Question* createQuestion(const char question[], const double answer)
{
    NumericQuestion* nq = new NumericQuestion(question, answer);
        return nq;
}
```

Thanks a lot. I really need your help to explain to me

Edit: Here is the declaration for Question

```
class Question
{
    char *q;
protected:
    void writeQuestion(ostream& ostr) const;
public:
    Question(const char question[])
    {
        int n = strlen(question);
        q =  new char[n];
        strcpy(q, question);
        cout << q;
        }
    void askQuestion() const;
    virtual void getAnswer();
    virtual bool isCorrect() const=0;
};
```

Edit: Declaration for NumericQuestion

```
class NumericQuestion : public Question
{
    double ans, geta;
public:
    NumericQuestion(const char question[], const double answer): Question(question)
    {
        ans = answer;
        getAnswer();
    }

    void getAnswer()
    {
        cout << "Answer: ";
        cin >> geta;
        isCorrect();
        }
    bool isCorrect()
    {
        return ((geta==ans)? true : false);
    }
};
```

Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post so much code

Comment: We also need to see the declaration for `Question`.

Comment: I already added the declaration for Question. Thanks

Comment: I just added it. Thanks immibis

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `isCorrect()` as `const` in `NumericQuestion`:

```
bool isCorrect() const  // <--- add const keyword here
```

The reason is because `const` is part of the method signature, like its name and parameters.  `isCorrect() const` is a different method than a function named `isCorrect()` that isn't const.

When you see a virtual method with `=0`, that means the method is "pure virtual".  The base class doesn't normally specify an implementation, but before any derived class can be instantiated, an implementation has to be defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The error is gone now. By the way, can you explain to me what is the above code doing exactly?

Comment: NumericQuestion is comparing the user's input with an answer, and returns true/false accordingly.  Question is a base class, so you could have other types of answers (say a letter, word, or phrase instead of a number) and the main code that uses `Question`s can handle any type of question, number, letters, or other.

Comment: I really appreciate for your help Philip.

Comment: Also those code from the top of of the question? I really need to understand those one. Thanks

Comment: The first section is incomplete.  It is a code fragment that declares an array of pointers-to-Question objects, and the `questions[numQuestions++] = createQuestion(...` part, if its called many times, like in a loop, would create a lot of question and store them in the array.